# find first non zero value in string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a column in R with each element like this
'005443333332222222211023222101110009988877665
Is there a way to find number of consecutive zero from starting position/ first appearance of non zero number? for the case above would be 2

Comment: is it string or numeric?  If it is string perhaps `as.vector(regexpr('[1-9]', str1)-1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the maximum of consecutive letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521119/count-the-maximum-of-consecutive-letters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use RegEx to pull the leading zeros off, and then count the characters:

```
string <- "005443333332222222211023222101110009988877665"

# the regex pattern (0+) matches one or more zeros, but only if they
# are at the beginning of the string, and captures in group 1

strLength <- nchar(gsub("^(0+).*","\\1", string))


print(strLength)
[1] 2
```

Edit: to handle the case when you don't have any leading zeros, you need to check if the string starts with a zero first:

```
strLength <- ifelse(grepl("^0+.*", string) == TRUE,nchar(gsub("^(0+).*","\\1", string)),0)
```

Because if your string is "123456", my first answer will return 6, when there are no leading zeros.

Comment: It's a column with string in each cell, the length of string can be fixed, this might work but you need to calculate length of string each time. Thanks!

Comment: @XinyuanZhang Not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying that you don't think you should have to calculate the length of the string of zeros for each row?

Comment: Also, I should point out that we're never calculating the length of the entire string, only the length of the output of our `gsub` function, which is just the leading zeros.