# Count the maximum of consecutive letters in a string

Tags: r, regex, string, string-matching, stringr

I have this vector:

```
vector <- c("XXXX-X-X", "---X-X-X", "--X---XX", "--X-X--X", "-X---XX-", "-X--X--X", "X-----XX", "X----X-X", "X---XX--", "XX--X---", "---X-XXX", "--X-XX-X")
```

I want to detect the maximum of consecutive times that appears X. So, my expected vector would be:

```
4, 1, 2, 1,2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2
```

Comment: Could also `sapply(gregexpr("X+", vector), function(x) max(attr(x, "match.length")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, we can split each `vector` into separate characters and then using `rle` find the `max` consecutive length for "X".

```
sapply(strsplit(vector, ""), function(x) {
   inds = rle(x)
   max(inds$lengths[inds$values == "X"])
})

#[1] 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 2
```

Comment: you can do the same without splitting if you work with `diff` on the result of `gregexpr` (with some little precaution ;-) ): `sapply(vector, function(x) {inds=rle(diff(gregexpr("X", x)[[1]])); max(max(inds$lengths[inds$values==1]), 0)+1})`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different approach.  We can split each term in the input vector on any number of dashes.  Then, find the substring with the greatest length.

```
sapply(vector, function(x) {
    max(nchar(unlist(strsplit(x, "-+"))))
})

XXXX-X-X ---X-X-X --X---XX --X-X--X -X---XX- -X--X--X X-----XX X----X-X 
       4        1        2        1        2        1        2        1 
X---XX-- XX--X--- ---X-XXX --X-XX-X 
       2        2        3        2
```

I suspect that `X` really just represents any non dash character, so we don't need to explicitly check for it.  If you *do* really only want to count `X`, then we can try removing all non `X` characters before we count:

```
sapply(vector, function(x) {
    max(nchar(gsub("[^X]", "", unlist(strsplit(x, "-+")))))
})
```

Comment: Without using `unlist`: `sapply(strsplit(vector, "-+"), function(x) max(nchar(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `strapply` in gsubfn to extract out the X... substrings applying `nchar` to each to count its number of character producing a list of vectors of lengths.  `sapply` the `max` function each such vector.

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapply(vector, "X+", nchar), max)
## [1] 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of `tidyverse` alternatives:

```
map_dbl(vector, ~sum(str_detect(., strrep("X", 1:8))))
# [1] 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 2
map_dbl(strsplit(vector,"-"), ~max(nchar(.)))
# [1] 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 2
```